# jquery autocomplete issue with special characters

Tags: jquery, ajax

i have implemented an autocomplete function on my script, it works perfect EXCEPT when user hits ñ key.

If user hits Ñ instead of ñ the script still works good, so my question is if anyone know what might be going on, if there´s kind of a mapping issue or how to solve it.......

some examples, if user writes "Ramallo" the function returns json perfect.
if user writes "cañuelas" script doesn´t return anything, but "CAÑUELAS, or caÑuelas" returns result ok.....

Any hint?g the string it´s conv

Answer (score 0):

ease yourself and change all UTF signs to ASCII equivalents